# iCloud: Can I control how much space "Optimise Mac Storage" tries to leave on the local machine?

Tags: macos, icloud, storage

When using "Optimize Mac Storage" for iCloud drive, how much space does iCloud try to leave on the machine? Is there anyway to adjust the amount of storage space that it leaves as it automatically adjusts which files are stored locally?

(I've had a lot of trouble finding any information and don't really see much in the way of settings)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find a way to do this in MacOS system settings. I am having the same trouble.

I got around this by creating a new drive with 40 GB so I always have some free space dedicated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a decent workout. The "iCloud Control" app. It let's me manually desync stuff from the machine freeing up space.

https://github.com/Obbut/iCloud-Control/releases